# python pandas - how to merge date from one and time from another column and create new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that comes from a database like this:
Both FltDate and ESTAD2 are datetime64[ns]

```
>>> print df[['Airport', 'FltDate', 'Carrier', 'ESTAD2']]

     Airport    FltDate Carrier              ESTAD2
0       EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 05:35:00
1       EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 06:40:00
2       EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 07:00:00
3       EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 07:05:00
4       EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 09:00:00
5       EDI 2017-06-18      I2 1899-12-30 11:05:00
6       EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 11:25:00
7       EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 13:45:00


>>> df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 214 entries, 0 to 213
Data columns (total 12 columns):
Airport         214 non-null object
FltDate         214 non-null datetime64[ns]
<snip>
ESTAD2          214 non-null datetime64[ns]
<snip>
dtypes: datetime64[ns](4), object(8)
memory usage: 20.1+ KB
```

How to get the **Date Part from FltDate** and **Time Part from ESTAD2.**

Result should be like this say for Row 0

```
2017-06-18 05:35:00 (that is 18Jun2017 of FltDate + 05:35 of ESTAD2)
```

I may replace ESTAD2 with above result.. or create a new column as FltDateTime.

Tried various ways and failed... like below... adding was unsuccessful.

```
>>> df.FltDate.dt.date

0      2017-06-18
1      2017-06-18
2      2017-06-18
>>> df.ESTAD2.dt.time

0      05:35:00
1      06:40:00
2      07:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.FltDate.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') +
                            df.ESTAD2.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
print (df)
  Airport    FltDate Carrier              ESTAD2                date
0     EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 05:35:00 2017-06-18 05:35:00
1     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 06:40:00 2017-06-18 06:40:00
2     EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 07:00:00 2017-06-18 07:00:00
3     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 07:05:00 2017-06-18 07:05:00
4     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 09:00:00 2017-06-18 09:00:00
5     EDI 2017-06-18      I2 1899-12-30 11:05:00 2017-06-18 11:05:00
6     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 11:25:00 2017-06-18 11:25:00
7     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 13:45:00 2017-06-18 13:45:00
```

Alternative solution:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.FltDate.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') +
                            df.ESTAD2.astype(str).str.split().str[1])

print (df)
  Airport    FltDate Carrier              ESTAD2                date
0     EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 05:35:00 2017-06-18 05:35:00
1     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 06:40:00 2017-06-18 06:40:00
2     EDI 2017-06-18    BACJ 1899-12-30 07:00:00 2017-06-18 07:00:00
3     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 07:05:00 2017-06-18 07:05:00
4     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 09:00:00 2017-06-18 09:00:00
5     EDI 2017-06-18      I2 1899-12-30 11:05:00 2017-06-18 11:05:00
6     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 11:25:00 2017-06-18 11:25:00
7     EDI 2017-06-18      BA 1899-12-30 13:45:00 2017-06-18 13:45:00
```

Comment: thk u. just wondering why can't we use df.FltDate.dt.date and df.ESTAD2.dt.time directly with some addition or datetime concat function. without the use of stftime. Is strftime the most optimal solution? please shed some light on this. i am asking this because i already have datetime object right.. then why bother to convert to string and back to datetime again.

Comment: My first solution was with convert to date, time, timedelta, but i think this is much faster and simplier.

Comment: Yes, but `date` and `time` in panas are objects, so use function is really problematic. So is necessary convert it to datetime - too complicated I think.

Comment: ok thk u... for some reason Row 0 shows new col 'date' as 2017-06-19 11:35:00 (instead of 2017-06-18 05:35:00) in my computer. this is unlike ur result. possibly to do with timezones?? i am in UTC+7.

Comment: Yes, it can be problem with timezones. check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling) and try `df.Date = df.Date.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')`

Comment: `Europe/London` change up to you :)

Comment: i think the problem is not timezones... even df.ESTAD2.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') returns.. 1899-12-30 05:35:00 (instead of just the 05:35:00) as our expectation... pls advise.

Comment: Problem is with all dates?

Comment: yes all the ESTAD2... however... df.FltDate.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') returns correct as expected ..'2017-06-18 '... only the df.ESTAD2.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') returns.. 1899-12-30 05:35:00 (instead of just the 05:35:00)... fyi the database is ms access with only timestamps in the fields. that is why the 1899-12-30 hh:mm:ss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138546/discussion-between-ihightower-and-jezrael).

Comment: 1 mydate = '1899-12-30 05:35:00' 
----> 2 print pd.to_datetime(mydate).strftime('%Y').head() 

ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900